# Best Way to Query inside ListField

Tags: mongoengine

I have the following code using MongoEngine:

```
class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    content = StringField()
    name = StringField(max_length=120)


class Post(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    author = StringField(required=True)
    tags = ListField(StringField(max_length=30))
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))

# Create a post:
post = Post(title="Quora rocks", author="Ross", tags=['tutorial', 'how-to'])
post.save()

comment1 = Comment(content="Great post!", name="john")
comment2 = Comment(content="Great post too!", name="dave")

post.comments.append(comment1)
post.comments.append(comment2)
post.save()

# Create a post:
post = Post(title="Books", author="Chandler")
post.save()

comment1 = Comment(content="Stupid post!", name="justin")
comment2 = Comment(content="Stupid post!", name="mark")

post.comments.append(comment1)
post.comments.append(comment2)
post.save()
```

I want to first get the post from Ross and then find the comment from john. What is the best way to do it ? I have MongoEngine 0.9.5

Comment: Present your code that you have already tried to reach a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem. We need to EmbeddedDocumentListField instead of ListField of EmbeddedDocumentField. This makes filtering the embedded document much easier.